# Combobox not firing SelectedIndexChanged when programmatically selecting index 0 (from -1)

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, .net-4.0

I have a combobox for wich I am using the SelectIndexChanged event to capture both user and programmatically changes.

Clearing and reloading the list bound to the combobox will fire the eventhandler with index -1 naturally.

But then with selectedindex=-1

```
combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0 ; // will NOT fire the event.
```

but

```
combobox1.SelectedIndex = 1 ; // or higher number WILL fire the event.
```

In both cases I AM programmatically changing the selextedindex and expect the event to be fired.

I verified the behavior in a simple form.

```
namespace cmbTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private BindingList<string> items = new BindingList<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.DataSource = items;
            loadItems();
        }

        private void loadItems()
        {
            items.Add("chair");
            items.Add("table");
            items.Add("coffemug");
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fired with selected item index:" + comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

            // Clear and reload items for whatever reason.
            items.Clear();
            loadItems();

            // try select old item index; if it doesnt exists, leave it.
            try { comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index; }
            catch { }
        }





    }
}
```

The form has a combobox1 and a button1.

EDIT for clarity (I hope):

1. Run program
2. Select 'chair'. Message "Fired with selected item index:0"
3. Hit button. Message "Fired with selected item index:-1"
4. Select 'table'. Message "Fired with selected item index:1"
5. Hit button. Messages "Fired with selected item index:-1" AND
   "Fired with selected item index:1".

I expect to get two messages  when hitting button when "chair" is selected  too, since I programmatically changes the index to 0.

So, why is this not working as I expect it to do, and what will be an acceptable workaround?

Comment: swallowing the exception ? That's not good. check if there is an exception being thrown.

Comment: referring to the catch{}? The try statement is only if the reload list doesnt have the item inde anymore. It is not the case here, and is not needed for this example

Comment: I can't see `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;` in your code. Where is the problem exactly ?

Comment: When you run the program and select index 0 (chair) and then press the button. It will not fire the event when selecting index 0 again.

Comment: I can't really reproduce your issue. Can you specify the exact steps that lead to this problem ?

Comment: @user3185569 . Run program. Select chair. Hit button. You will only get a change to -1. If you select table and hit the button you will get the -1 index AND change to index 1. Theres the difference that I dont expect.

Comment: This is because the saved index is 0. When you clear the items it is -1; When you load the items, the index is 0. When you set it to zero , it doesn't change .

Comment: When you set the datasource items , the index is automatically changed to 0 (No event is fired) and this is very good design decision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117597/discussion-between-user3185569-and-nick-sick).

Comment: check the workaround posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your first item is added to the items collection the index is automatically changed to 0. That's why when your previous index is saved as 0, and then you set it again using this line `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;`, the index is not changed. That's why the event is not fired.

Looking at the source code for the ComboBox, the event is not fired in 2 cases : Either an expcetion is thrown, or the index is set to the same value that it is was.

If you really want some hack around this, you can do it this way:

```
int index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

// Clear and reload items for whatever reason.
items.Clear();
loadItems();

if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == index)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

// try select old item index; if it doesnt exists, leave it.
try { comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index; }
catch
{
}
```

Comment: You are right. The selected index is set to 0 when the list is set again. The odd thing is that my debug window still says that it is -1 before setting it to 0. But an extra message box clearly stated the selected index already was 0 before trying to set it back to 0.

Comment: It gave me som tips, but since my event handler always will skip over the -1, I will propably go with forcing the selected item to -1 in the loaditems method.

Comment: @NickSick this will not work. Try it. You need to play with the unsubscribe/subscribe to the event in order for this to work. Just exactly like I did. If you find this answer helpful, you can mark it accepted.